# Why do I lose type information when using boost::copy_exception?

Tags: c++, exception, boost

When I use `boost::copy_exception` to copy an exception to an `exception_ptr`, I lose type information. Take a look at the following code:

```
try {
    throw std::runtime_error("something");
} catch (exception& e) {
    ptr = boost::copy_exception(e);
}
if (ptr) {
    try {
        boost::rethrow_exception(ptr);
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        cout << boost::diagnostic_information(e) << endl;
    }
}
```

From this, I get the following output:

```
N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implISt9exceptionEE
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<std::exception>
std::exception::what: N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implISt9exceptionEE
```

So basically `boost::copy_exception` statically copied the argument it got.

This problem is solved if I throw my exception with `boost::enable_current_exception` instead, like this.

```
try {
    throw boost::enable_current_exception(std::runtime_error("something"));
} catch (...) {
    ptr = boost::current_exception();
}
if (ptr) {
    try {
        boost::rethrow_exception(ptr);
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        cout << boost::diagnostic_information(e) << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that sometimes the exceptions are thrown by a library that does not use `boost::enable_current_exception`. In this case, is there any way to put the exception into an `exception_ptr` apart from catching each kind of possible exception one by one and use `boost::copy_exception` on each one?

Comment: I am not really familiar with boost exceptions, but did you try a simple `throw;` in the `catch` block which throws the current exception again while preserving its type?

Comment: You're probably suffering from the [slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design, and your analysis is correct: the static type is used, not the dynamic type. In fact, to avoid this surprise, `boost::copy_exception` became `std::make_exception_ptr` during the process that led to C++11. That way, it's clearer that `current_exception` (whether the Boost version or the C++11 one) is the correct thing to use to correctly capture, well, the current exception. I highly recommend using `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION`, or at least `boost::throw_exception`, when it comes to using Boost.Exception-enabled exceptions in your code.

When it comes to third-party code, there is no solution other than the one you already mentioned, or some other moral equivalent (like `dynamic_cast`-ing to the different leaf classes that make up the exception type hierarchy or hierarchies, or `typeid` abuse).

In this respect exception handling is the same as working with one or more hierarchy of polymorphic types, and the operation you're attempting in this case is a virtual copy, also known as cloning: either your code is intrusively designed to support that (as is the case when using e.g. `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(e);` instead of `throw e;`), or you're going to painfully walk the inheritance tree. Note that you can at least refactor that pain into just one site, such that you'd end up with e.g.

```
try {
    third_party_api();
} catch(...) {
    ptr = catch_exceptions_from_api();
}
```